# Native speakers using "house" instead of "flat", "apartment", "condo"

Tags: word-usage, colloquialisms

I sometimes hear native speakers of English use the word "house" instead of "flat" (BrE) and "apartment"/"condo" (AmE).

[This YouTube video with a time stamp](https://youtu.be/1JjCtRhmQTo?t=45) is a case in point. The girl keeps alternating between saying "house" and "apartment".

My question: **Is such usage acceptable in colloquial English?**

Comment: I (US) haven't heard this usage until I saw the clip you linked. But the interviewee is originally from the UK, so maybe this common in BrE?

Comment: 'House' can mean 'household' or 'home'. There is an overlap in semantic usage. I am saying this as a native speaker of English (BrE).

Answer (score 5):

These words—flats, apartments, condos, town houses, houses—have not only the descriptive meaning one might find in a dictionary, but, especially in the case of *house,* a more general meaning as the place one lives or, in its verbal form, the place where one is housed, or where an activity or organization is housed.

Thus I might invite someone to dinner at my house, whether my house is a set of rooms above a store, a flat, a basement room, or a freestanding two-story mansion. So each word has the potential to spread out in implications and nuance beyond the initial limitations your first forė into this vocabulary might suggest.

The use of house is neither regional, dialectic, nor informal in AmE or BrE, although typical use may vary on the two sides of the pond.

The basic idea is that human language is not limited as is programming language.

You will get familiar with usage through reading and listening rather than dictionaries. Thus you might encounter “My friend houses his vintage Porsche in a garage.”

Comment: I've never heard this usage in AmE. If I needed a general word to describe the place where one lives, I would always use "home" (or informally "my place"), not "house." I suspect this is more common in BrE.

Comment: "Home" and "my place" are good too.  Since shelter is important, there's a lot of vocabulary and expressions about it.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't think "house" is ever used that way where I am (Northeast US).

Comment: @alphabet I live in NY and hear "house" being used that way all the time. "Let's go to my house" is interchangeable with "let's go to my apartment."

Comment: Interesting. I live in the Boston area and haven't heard that usage (or at least haven't noticed it).